# how to set dynmic query param value on rest camel xml routing

Tags: java, apache-camel

i have camel routing like below, on log i can print "update Id : 1113" ,  but when calling rest service with query param,
i can not get value of ${property.id}. logging on rest server = "/test/update?id=$%7Bproperty.id%7D".
how to pass query param value dynmicly, in camel rest xml routing ?

```
            <camel:setProperty propertyName="id">
            <camel:jsonpath>$.id</camel:jsonpath></camel:setProperty>
            <camel:log logName="Fuse_Service" message="update Id : ${property.id}"/>

                <simple>${property.http_method} == 'PUT'</simple>
                <camel:setHeader headerName="Content-Type"><constant>application/json</constant> 
                </camel:setHeader>
                <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod"><constant>PUT</constant> 
                </camel:setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery">
                 <constant>id=${property.id}</constant>        
                </setHeader>
                <camel:to uri="http4://{{test.api.url}}/test/update" />
```

Answer (score -1):

it is my mistake i use constant element:

> < constant>id=${property.id}</ constant>.

the proper one is using simple element

> < simple> id=${property.id} </ simple>